# eslint angular - cant find .eslintrc

Tags: angular, eslint

I want to install eslint in my angular project I have run the two install steps as mentioned here https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-angular#default-eslint-configuration-file but it then says add stuff to your .eslintrc file. But I dont have one!

Where should this .eslintrc file be and should it have been created for me when I ran the two install steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the missing piece I had to run this command

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-angular
```

I then can see an **eslint.rs.json** file, this video helped me see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km7RuJEfE0c

I can now run the `ng lint` command and its seems to work, also add the Visual Studio Code ESLint plugin and can now see issues as I work.